# React Native unable to find CSS Modules

Tags: css, react-native, expo

I wanted to use CSS modules instead of StyleSheets for my React Native Project (On Expo 49) but I get the error: Unable to resolve "./App.module.css" from "src\app\App.js"

My import statement is:

```js
import styles from "./App.module.css";
```

My file structure is:

- src:

  - components
  - app:

    - App.js
    - App.module.css
    - pages:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't do it at all**. React Native has got its own rules. Even for React Native Web you can't import a CSS file and style your components in React Native development area.

You must use the following example to style your React Native components:

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```